# Problem : Firefox / selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

Since I upgraded my ubuntu impish to jammy (22.04.1 LTS), I have problem in my python script using selenium with firefox (before it worked very well).
Below you will find the "generic" message of selenium trouble:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

And here you will find the result of the geckodriver.log:

```
1665336675615   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:46459
1665336676102   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "--remote-debugging-port" "47893" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilet2tISh"
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
*** You are running in headless mode
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt

(firefox:3302): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:32:19.699: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/snap.firefox/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(firefox:3302): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:32:19.737: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/snap.firefox/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(firefox:3302): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:32:19.737: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/snap.firefox/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(firefox:3302): dconf-CRITICAL **: 19:32:19.737: unable to create directory '/run/user/0/snap.firefox/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
```

What I have done to "fix" this problem was to directly create the directory /run/user/0 with the full access (777).
After that the problem was stil here, it's not the same message, I have only this one:

```
*** You are running in headless mode
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL initialize failed
[GFX1-]: RenderCompositorSWGL failed mapping default framebuffer, no dt
```

and the selenium message is still the same:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

I found some similar problems on internet but nothing to help me to fix this one.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Firefox is a snap package in Ubuntu 22, maybe that's the source of your problem. Try reinstalling it as a .deb package, and try again. Instructions: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Perfect!! It works! I followed the procedure and everything works again. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. maybe I should make it a response?

Comment: Yes, it could help someone else :)